# operands function works differently inside a procedure

Tags: maple

Let's define a procedure

```
[> f:=proc(s)
     s:={1}: {op(s),2};
   end proc:
```

then

```
[> f('s');
                            {2, {1}}
```

but

```
[> s:={1}: {op(s),2};
                             {1, 2}
```

So why do we have a *different* result?
Using a local variable we can get the expected result though:

```
[> f:=proc(s) local S;
     S:={1}: s:=S; {op(S),2};
   end proc:
   f('s');
                             {1, 2}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to the procedure is written to have a side-effect on the uneval-quoted name passed as argument. (Personally I think that is an evil programming practice, and ill consequences are not unexpected.)

Since you have wrapped the name in uneval-quotes, then an extra `eval` allows you access. Eg,

```
f:=proc(s)
   s:={1}; {op(eval(s)),2};
end proc:

f('s');

          {1, 2}
```

Comment: Thanks, could you clarify more about "evil programming practice"? Did you mean that 1) we should always use _eval_ for every argument of a function or 2) we shouldn't use quoted arguments (i.e. use f(s) instead of f('s'))?
My actual function has 3 arguments and the last one is optional (it's some intermediate result, which I need to return sometimes), I call the function this way: f(x,y,'s').
What is a good practice in this case? Should s be a global variable instead? (I think this could increase probability of more errors, at least in my case)

Comment: The few stock commands which use side-effect assignment on a unevaluated name (as argument) predate the functionality multiple-assignment. But now you can have a proc return a sequence of two results and even assign them together to other names. There's little need for the side-effect on a passed name technique. But if you really feel you must then use locals and only use the passed name for being assigned its final result. (*Further* using that assigned `s` inside the proc is what I meant as evil.) I don't like the whole technique of assigning to a passed name, but that doesn't make it evil.